# Storing Wordpress statements as a function for multiple use?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, if-statement

I find myself using something like this a lot in my sites:

```
if (is_tree(88) || is_tree(4595) || is_page(2) || is_category(70) ) { 
    ...do something
}
```

I may use this in several template files which means as my site grows and I need to add new conditions to the statement I have to apply the changes everywhere in my theme.

Is it possible to store this somewhere (I'm thinking `functions.php`) and call it in the template files?
That way, when I need to change it, I can do so once and it's applied everywhere.

Comment: You can create **constants**. Add on your functions.php (example) **define('PAGE_IMPRINT', 88);** and on your Statement **is_tree(PAGE_IMPRINT)**. Than you must only change the functions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a function might help. That way, you can add it to the `functions.php` file and include it across pages and you can add more conditional parameters in one place.

Something like this:

```
function if_condn(){
    return (is_tree(88) || is_tree(4595) || is_page(2) || is_category(70));
}
```

And use it like this in other theme files:

```
if(if_condn()){
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's the one! Cheers.